# CakePHP 2x forward from view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

In CakePHP 2x I want to display some text when some condition is met and forward to another page when another condition is met, something like the code below. But this second part is not working.I know redirect only works from controller. Is there any way to do this in view?

```
if ($enable==2){ 
    echo $introduction; 
    } 
elseif ($enable==1){ 
    **$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages' , 'action' => 'home'));**
     }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you do the redirect in the controller, that would be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use js helper as shown bellow:

```
$this->Js->domReady('window.location.href="/your/URL/Here";');
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to handle the solutions. CakePHP redirects should really be handled in the Controller.  Using Javascript is a bad idea for several reasons (browser compatibility, best practices, automagic URL routing, SEO, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic is correct, but your redirect() url is not.

Your Controller (not your View) should have this as the redirect:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'home'));
```

The PagesController works a little differently than your other controllers. By default, it uses the 'display' action to render pages.  You then pass the page name after that.

Here's some more info on the PagesController: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html

Hope that helps.